# Spark installation failed on cygwin

Tags: windows, scala, apache-spark, cygwin

I'm currently installing spark using cygwin terminal, I followed the steps indicated here, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_spark/apache_spark_installation.htm, everything was fine until the last step..

I added the "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/spark/bin"  line to ~/.bashrc file.

When I run the $spark-shell command, it gives me this error..

/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-class: line 86: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin/bin/java: No such file or directory

I tried searching for answers online but unfortunately nothing worked for me.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in:

/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-class: line 86: **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin/bin/java**: No such file or directory

You have two "bin" - one from Windows "\bin" and one from cygwin "/bin"

You can modify the JAVA_HOME environment variable - and set it to be **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75** (or the actual path of jdk)

I'd make a backup of /usr/local/spark/bin/spark-class and try to change the following line in /usr/local/spark/bin/spark-class

```
RUNNER="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java
```

to be:

```
RUNNER="${JAVA_HOME}\java
```

And then run again the $spark-shell command

Comment: Oh Thanks @Yaron I think it worked.. but when i run the $spark-shell command, it's showing another error..  

**Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main** 

I tried searching for the spark launcher but it's not existing in the spark folder. what to do now?

Comment: What did you change ? Java-home or the script?

Comment: I changed the script, since java_home is already on the system variables.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've no idea how to solve the new problem. Which version of spark/hadoop did you install? Do you mush install it on cygwin (what about installing it on Linux/Windows?)

Comment: Now, the problem is that cygwin convert path in SPARK_HOME variable that is passed as classpath from c:\something to /cygdrive/c/something. And /cygdrive/c/something is not understandable for Windows JVM. I have no solution at the moment, but the fact is that the script is probably not usable from Cygwin and most likely should be rewritten for this environment.